# Unreliable Flaky Booting for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am trying to diagnose my problem booting Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Precision 7740 Laptop.

Recently, the booting on my system has become unreliable and flaky.  Use of the GRUB recovery menu shows multiple kernels, probably due to updates.  However, none of these work reliably, including the most recent.

Using the recovery mode seems to proceed okay without reporting any errors, and but resuming the boot seems to always fails to a black screen with a blinking cursor.

The only thing that works now is updating GRUB from the recovery menu and then continuing the boot. What steps should I take to figure out what is going on?

The boot-repair program generated the following pastebin
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7wd7sFDQpH/

After running sudo apt update and sudo apt list --upgradable, I see some relevant items:

`grub-efi-amd64-signed/focal-updates 1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.142.5+2.04-1ubuntu26.3]
grub-pc-bin/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.3]
grub-pc/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.3]
grub2-common/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.3]
im-config/focal-updates,focal-updates 0.44-1ubuntu1.2 all [upgradable from: 0.44-1ubuntu1.1]
initramfs-tools-bin/focal-updates 0.136ubuntu6.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.136ubuntu6.2]
initramfs-tools-core/focal-updates,focal-updates 0.136ubuntu6.3 all [upgradable from: 0.136ubuntu6.2]
initramfs-tools/focal-updates,focal-updates 0.136ubuntu6.3 all [upgradable from: 0.136ubuntu6.2]`

After running apt upgrade, I see the following actions:

`Setting up grub2-common (2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...
Setting up qemu-system-x86 (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.5) ...
Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...
Setting up fdisk (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...
Sourcing file /etc/default/grub' Sourcing file /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Setting up qemu-utils (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.5) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools-core (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.142.6+2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...
Installing grub to /boot/efi.
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.`

After running boot-repair and attempting to reboot, the standard boot still does not work properly.   Going to the recovery mode root menu and waiting seems to work, however.

Comment: What model Dell? Have you updated UEFI? You should only have two kernels unless an upgrade and you did not remove all the old ones. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: When boot fails, what are the symptoms? What happens?

Comment: My model is a Dell Precision 7740, a recent model. Running update-grub shows Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings </pre>

Comment: When boot fails, the machine just sits there with a blinking cursor.  When boot succeeds, it works as normal.